# Injecting multiple implementations of same interface through Instance<T> in test class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mockito

I'm struggling with writing unit tests for one of my classes. The main class:

```
public class MainClass {
    ...

    private Instance<BaseInterface> steps;

    @Inject
    public void setSteps(Instance<BaseInterface> steps) { this.steps = steps; }

    @Asynchronous
    public void callingMethod() {
        ...
        ImmutableList<BaseInterface> stepList = STEP_ORDERING.immutableSortedCopy(steps); // Here the NPE is being thrown when calling method from test class
        ...
    }
}
```

There are 5 specific implementations of `BaseInterface`, all 5 are correctly injected through setter by CDI at runtime (one of the implementation is annotated with @Named, the rest do not have this annotation).

However, calling the wrapper method `callingMethod` from the test class throws NPE. The test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MainClassTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
    @Mock
    private Instance<BaseInterface> steps;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ...

        mainClass.callingMethod(); // Throws NPE

        ...
    }
}
```

As far as I'm concerned, Mockito does not take care of bean dependency injection like CDI. Therefore, is there a way in which to tell Mockito to mock all implementations of `BaseInterface` and inject them into the `MainClass`?

Version details: Java 8, Mockito 2.8.9, JUnit 4

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The problem was not caused by Mockito, but by the method `STEP_ORDERING.immutableSortedCopy` which behind the scenes calls `iterator()` method from `Instance<T>` which returned `null` (since it extends `Iterable<T>`).

**Mocking the iterator does the trick:**

```
Iterator<BaseInterface> iteratorMock = (Iterator<BaseInterface>) mock(Iterator.class);
when(steps.iterator()).thenReturn(iteratorMock);
```

**or by creating an actual instance of iterator**:

```
Iterator<BaseInterface> iteratorActual = new Iterator<BaseInterface>(){
// implementation here
};
when(steps.iterator()).thenReturn(iteratorActual );
```